# Pattern Matching and Replacement in R for a Table of Averages

Tags: r, replace, average

I'm a beginner in R and am scratching my head at something.

I'm trying to make a table of averages for specific measurements according to rainfall patterns. (C2 is one site name.) In some cases, the measurements are below a specific threshold (for example, in the data set one flow measurement may be `<0.01` ft/sec.) Because `<0.01` is not numeric, I deleted the `<` with the `gsub` function and ran the averages according to the following:

```
data_C2_numeric <- data_C2
data_C2_numeric$flow = as.numeric(gsub("<","",data_C2_numeric$flow, ignore.case = TRUE))
table_averages_C2 <- aggregate(data_C2_numeric, list(data_C2_numeric$weather), FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And this appears to work. However, once the averages table is created, I want to reinsert the `<` symbol **but** only if `data_C2$flow` contains a `<` symbol in its column.

I know this command will insert the `<` but will insert it regardless of whether `data_C2$flow` contains `<`

```
table_averages_C2$flow = gsub("^", "<", table_averages_C2$flow)
```

And I know this command is used to determine if `data_C2` contains a `<`

```
startsWith(as.character(data_C2$flow), "<")
```

So how can I merge these two commands into one so that the `<` symbol is inserted into `table_averges_C2`only if it was present in `data_C2$flow`?

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. *I'm quoting this to point out you need to make it reproducible - include the example data*

Comment: The question isn't clear, how would you insert a symbol that was present in the original data if the result is an aggregate? The result will have less rows than the original.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. It's like I'm averaging <0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, and 0.5. I drop the < so its now 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, and 0.5. The mean is 0.3. I then want to add the < back to say <0.3. Like converting <0.1 to numeric then converting the mean back to string.

Comment: So like, if `data_C2$flow` contains <0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5. `data_C2_numeric$flow` contains 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, and 0.5. <0.1/0.1, 0.2 are DRY while 0.3,0.4,0.5 are RAIN. I want the average for RAIN to contain a `<` while the average for DRY to not contain a `<` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `sapply` function along with `any(grepl(...))` or `any(startsWith(...))` to check if any element that went into the aggregated data contained a `<`

```
#create data
data_C2<-data.frame(original=c("<0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "0.4", "0.5"))
data_C2$flow<-as.numeric(gsub("<","",data_C2$original, ignore.case = TRUE))
data_C2$weather<-c("DRY", "DRY", "RAIN", "RAIN", "RAIN")

data_C2
      original flow weather
1     <0.1  0.1     DRY
2      0.2  0.2     DRY
3      0.3  0.3    RAIN
4      0.4  0.4    RAIN
5      0.5  0.5    RAIN

table_averages_C2 <- aggregate(flow~weather, data=data_C2, FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#check if any flow number in weather group has "<" sign
table_averages_C2$qualifier<-sapply(table_averages_C2$weather, function(group) {
  ifelse(any(grepl("<", data_C2$original[which(data_C2$weather==group)])), "<", "")})

#add "<" to flow average
table_averages_C2$flow<-paste0(table_averages_C2$qualifier, table_averages_C2$flow)

table_averages_C2[,-3]
  weather  flow
1     DRY <0.15
2    RAIN   0.4
```